# order subcategories under categories with a common table expression from one physical table

Tags: sql-server, common-table-expression, recursive-query

I have a simple table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ProductCategories](
    [ProductCategoryId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [ProductCategoryParentId] [int] NULL,
    [ProductCategoryName] [varchar](500) NULL
)
```

and I'm trying to recursively select data from it but have that data ordered like so:

[image: CTE Ordering]

I have this common table expression I'm using:

```
WITH Categories AS
(
    SELECT Cat.ProductCategoryId
        ,Cat.ProductCategoryName
        ,Cat.ProductCategoryParentId
        ,CAST('Root' AS VARCHAR(500)) AS 'ParentCategory'
        ,0 AS 'Level'
    FROM ProductCategories Cat
    WHERE Cat.ProductCategoryParentId = 0

    UNION ALL

    SELECT Cat.ProductCategoryId
        ,Cat.ProductCategoryName
        ,Cat.ProductCategoryParentId
        ,c2.ProductCategoryName AS 'ParentCategory'
        ,LEVEL + 1
    FROM ProductCategories CAT
    INNER JOIN Categories c2 ON cat.ProductCategoryParentId = c2.ProductCategoryId
    WHERE c2.ProductCategoryId != 0
)
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM Categories
ORDER BY level
,ProductCategoryParentId
,ProductCategoryName
```

which does great for recursing my table and returning the different levels, but I'd like to have the results ordered with sub categories under parent categories direct from sql so I don't have to do any reordering code-side.

I can't wrap my head around this.

any suggestions?

TIA

Comment: You may order by ultimate parent id first, then by level

Comment: Order by Parent, Category, Sub-Category.   Of course, you'll have to add those to the CTE, and not include them in the final select if you don't want them.

Comment: are you saying in my final select?  That doesn't work, that just orders by the parent ID which doesn't place the sub categories under the categories.  It lists all categories, then all sub categories.

Comment: @BlairHolmes, you may want add some sample data, so we can see where you have issues

Comment: I think this question is answered here: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/43560/parent-child-tree-hierarchical-order

Comment: Thanks Kevin.  I actually found something very similar here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3986627/sql-ordering-a-common-table-expression but now I'm facing an issue where I can't sub-order the items alphabetically.  Any ideas on that?

Comment: nevermind, one of the comments in that link you supplied addressed the sub-order issue.  Thanks @KevinSuchlicki!  That got me there.